# Add controls programmatically to specific screen location in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm starting out with Android and trying to put together a little app to let users enter up to 8 player names, then potentially add more on the click of a Button.  I've defined my 5 standard EditText fields and 2 Buttons as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AddNamesActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:hint="Player 1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player2"
        android:hint="Player 2"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player3"
        android:hint="Player 3"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player4"
        android:hint="Player 4"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player5"
        android:hint="Player 5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addPlayerBtn"
        android:text="Add Player"
        android:onClick="addPlayerButtonClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pickTeamsBtn"
        android:text="Pick Teams"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like when the User clicks the "Add Player" button, it gets added programmatically between the Add Player button and the last EditText field.

My method to add a Button programmatically seems to work nicely, but I'm just not sure how to specify the exact position I want.  Also, is there any further setting changes to make to have the device auto add a scroll bar when too many EditTexts are added to the screen?  Or will Android handle this for me?

```
public void addPlayerButtonClick(View view) {
    //Set our layout up
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    EditText newPlayer = new EditText(this);
    newPlayer.setHint("Player");
    newPlayer.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //Add button to screen
    layout.addView(newPlayer);
}
```

Comment: For Scroll you can have the reference from here.    http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/

Comment: And for adding to the listview,as per my knowledge in android use  SharedPreference to store the old values present in the list and also the latest one and on clicking Add Button try to inflate the list from Sharepreference

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put LinearLayout in a scroll view if you want it to automatically add scroll if there are many controls.
As for where you want to add, you can write:

```
layout.addView(newPlayer,0); // Second argument specifies index. 0 means at start
```